# krb-protos.h Syntax error: possible missing identifier?

Tags: c, kerberos, aix, openssh, xlc

I am using krb-protos.h from krb4 package for my openssh code compilation on AIX 7.1 but facing below error,

```
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 71.9: 1506-046 (S) Syntax error.
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 75.15: 1506-275 (S) Unexpected text c encountered.
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 76.9: 1506-276 (S) Syntax error: possible missing identifier?
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 82.9: 1506-335 (S) Parameter identifier list contains multiple occurrences of KTEXT.
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 74.1: 1506-282 (S) The type of the parameters must be specified in a prototype.
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 88.15: 1506-275 (S) Unexpected text pkt encountered.
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 89.9: 1506-276 (S) Syntax error: possible missing identifier?
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 87.1: 1506-282 (S) The type of the parameters must be specified in a prototype.
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 98.15: 1506-275 (S) Unexpected text tkt encountered.
"/usr/athena/include/krb-protos.h", line 99.9: 1506-276 (S) Syntax error: possible missing identifier?
```

snap of krb-protos.h file :

```
. . . 

 68 
 69 void KRB_LIB_FUNCTION
 70 afs_string_to_key __P((
 71         const char *str,
 72         const char *cell,
 73         des_cblock *key));
 74 
 75 int KRB_LIB_FUNCTION
 76 create_ciph __P((
 77         KTEXT c,
 78         unsigned char *session,
 79         char *service,
 80         char *instance,
 81         char *realm,
 82         u_int32_t life,
 83         int kvno,
 84         KTEXT tkt,
 85         u_int32_t kdc_time,
 86         des_cblock *key));
 87 
 88 int KRB_LIB_FUNCTION
 89 cr_err_reply __P((
 90         KTEXT pkt,
 91         char *pname,
 92         char *pinst,
 93         char *prealm,
 94         u_int32_t time_ws,
 95         u_int32_t e,
 96         char *e_string));
 97 

. . .
```

I am using xlc compiler on AIX. any idea what could be the issue ?

### xlc compiler with options :

```
xlc -DAFS -DKRB4 -L/usr/athena/lib -I/usr/athena/include -DSTATIC_AFS_SYSCALLS=1 -DOPENSSL_DES_LIBDES_COMPATIBILITY=1   -bloadmap -I. -I.  -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/gssapi -I/usr/include/gssapi -DSSHDIR=\"/etc/ssh\"  -D_PATH_SSH_PROGRAM=\"/opt/freeware/bin/ssh\"  -D_PATH_SSH_ASKPASS_DEFAULT=\"/opt/freeware/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass\"  -D_PATH_SFTP_SERVER=\"/opt/freeware/libexec/openssh/sftp-server\"  -D_PATH_SSH_KEY_SIGN=\"/opt/freeware/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign\"  -D_PATH_SSH_PKCS11_HELPER=\"/opt/freeware/libexec/openssh/ssh-pkcs11-helper\" -D_PATH_SSH_PIDDIR=\"/var/run\"  -D_PATH_PRIVSEP_CHROOT_DIR=\"/var/empty\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c ssh_api.c -o ssh_api.o
```

Comment: Please give a link to this 'krb4 package'.

Comment: I don't have link for krb4 package, I got rpm of krb4 from admin.

Comment: Could you paste the full xlC compiler invocation command? Also, could you show us what line 71 looks like? Is that the first line that an error is encountered?

Comment: Added xlc compiler options and file lines.

Comment: There is a good chance that the macro __P(x) is not visible. You probably need to include the proper header.

Comment: Agree that something looks to be wrong with `__P()`, but without more details, it's hard to say what exactly. If you can use the `-E` option with `xlc`, that will produce a pre-processed file that the IBM compiler team can look at. Are you able to open a [Service Request](https://www-946.ibm.com/support/servicerequest/Home.action) for this?